# Flask Python Buttons

Tags: python, html, button, flask

I'm trying to create two buttons on a page. Each one I would like to carry out a different Python script on the server. So far I have only managed to **get/collect** one button using.

```
def contact():
  form = ContactForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    return 'Form posted.'

  elif request.method == 'GET':
     return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

What would I need to change based on button pressed?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Give your two buttons the same name and different values:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Do Something">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Do Something Else">
```

Then in your Flask view function you can tell which button was used to submit the form:

```
def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'Do Something':
            pass # do something
        elif request.form['submit_button'] == 'Do Something Else':
            pass # do something else
        else:
            pass # unknown
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Comment: I think it's better to have different names. And check name - not value. If 'do_something' in request.form...

Comment: Why not use `id` instead of `name`? In this case it would have been better.

Comment: It also works with <button type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Do Something">BUTTON</button>

Comment: @Jimilian I'm a bit late in asking, but why do you think it's better to check `name` rather than `value`?

Answer (score 39):

The appropriate way for doing this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if 'download' in request.form:
            pass # do something
        elif 'watch' in request.form:
            pass # do something else
```

Put `watch` and `download` buttons into your template:

```
<input type="submit" name="download" value="Download">
<input type="submit" name="watch" value="Watch">
```

Comment: `watch` and `download` what? "watch" and "download" for the values of the name attributes? I'm assuming that's what that must be, because of the Python `if x in dict` syntax. I like this answer better. It just needs that clarification.

Answer (score 23):

In case anyone was still looking and came across this SO post like I did.

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="open" value="Open">
    <input type="submit" name="close" value="Close">
</form>
```

---

```
def contact():
    if "open" in request.form:
        pass
    elif "close" in request.form:
        pass
    return render_template('contact.html')
```

Simple, concise, and it works. Don't even need to instantiate a form object.

Comment: I have attempted to make use this code snippet in my own flask program, but wasn't able to make it work:

    # Validate Buttons
    if "Minute" in request.form:
        f = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
        f.write('min')
        f.close()

Comment: @skrhee Make sure you're wrapping the `<input>`'s with a <form> tag. With some troubleshooting, you should be able to determine whether your view function is being called, and then whether "Minute" is in the `request.form` object to find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 18):

I handle it in the following way:

```
<html>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="/">

                <input type="submit" value="Encrypt" name="Encrypt"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Decrypt" name="Decrypt" />

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python Code :

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    
    @app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        print(request.method)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.form.get('Encrypt') == 'Encrypt':
                # pass
                print("Encrypted")
            elif  request.form.get('Decrypt') == 'Decrypt':
                # pass # do something else
                print("Decrypted")
            else:
                # pass # unknown
                return render_template("index.html")
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            # return render_template("index.html")
            print("No Post Back Call")
        return render_template("index.html")
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

Comment: For me this was the only working solution running on a Raspberry PI with Python3  :)

Comment: Nice example, though it seems you have a redundant `/div`

Answer (score 6):

I think this solution is good:

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.submit.data:
            pass
        elif form.submit2.data:
            pass
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Form:

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):

    submit = SubmitField('Do this')
    submit2 = SubmitField('Do that')
```

Comment: Looks like FlaskForm [is part of a separate flask_wtf package](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_wtf.FlaskForm).

Answer (score 1):

Apply (different) name attribute to both buttons like

```
<button name="one">
```

and catch them in request.data.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to catch them in Python?

Answer (score 0):

this work to me
.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
     if request.form.get('new Token'):
#something
     if request.form.get('custom Token'):
#something diferent
```

.html

```
<form method="post" >
<input type="submit" name="new Token" value="new Token">
<input type="submit" name="custom Token" value="custom Token">
</form>
```

works because the button that you do not oppress ,return None to python.
nice day