# Python Flask request.form not working

Tags: python, flask, request.form

I have a question about Python.
I am trying to get multiple buttons in one form, but it isn't working out.

I have tried using `if 'elem' in request.form`, but that isn't working, because the submit's doesn't go in `request.form`. You have any idea how it comes?

I have already tried solving it with this: [Flask Python Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794695/flask-python-buttons)
But that didn't work out.
Google isn't working for me aswell, hence why trying it on here.

Python code:

```
@app.route('/option_new_sender/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def option_new_sender():
# Add selected elements to session['added_elements']
if 'add_elem' in request.form:
    return 'a'
# Delete Selected elements from session['added_elems']
elif 'remove_elem' in request.form:
    return 'b'
# Reset verwijderd session['added_elems']
elif 'reset' in request.form:
    return 'c'
# Verzend form en voegt toe aan 'entries_plot_list
elif 'send_form' in request.form:
    return 'd'
else:
    return 'e'
```

HTML code:

```
<form action={{url_for("option_new_sender")}} method="POST">
<h2>Een nieuwe grafiek toevoegen</h2>
Titel: <input type="text" name="title" value={{title}}><br/>
Perc: <input type="text" name="perc" value={{perc}}><br/>
<select name = "added_elems" multiple size="5">
    {% for elem in elems %}
        <option value = "{{elem}}">{{elem}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<button type= "submit" value = "remove_elem">Remove element</button>
</br></br>
Element: 
<select name = "elem" multiple size = "5">
    {% for elem in all_elems %} 
        <option value = "{{elem}}">{{elem}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<button type="submit" value = "add_elem">Add element</button>
<button type="submit" value = "send_form">Verzenden</button>
<button type="submit" value = "reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

It doesn't matter what I try, for some reason the Submit always ends at 'e'.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried simply printing out `request.form` to see what it looks like?

Comment: Michelle: yes, I have! Request.form gives this, when there is nothing selected in the tables:
ImmutableMultiDict([('title', ''), ('perc', '')])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any element to be submitted in the HTTP POST, it needs to have a `name` attribute. Your buttons don't, so you need to add them.

```
<button type="submit" name="add_elem" value="add">Add element</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! This kinda solved the issue. I think I must have swapped 'value' and 'name' in my head.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<button type="submit" name="add_elem" value="add">Add element</button>
<button type="submit" name="send_form" value="send">Verzenden</button>
<button type="submit" name="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
```