# How to submit a form but indicate different purpose for data, python/flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a form around a table and in the table one of the columns has a checkbox for each row.

```
Item    Amount    Select
-------------------------
apple   10        [x]
banana  5         [ ]
orange  23        [ ]
```

I then have two buttons, one deletes the row, the other does something else in the backend with the same information.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('do_action') }}" method="post">
    <table>
    ...content
        <input name="check" type="checkbox">
    </table
<button type='submit'>Delete Row</button>
<button type='submit'>Update</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way to attach some sort of context to the form depending on the button I press?

I want my route in the backend to know what to do

```
@app.route('/do_action', methods=['POST'])
def do_action():
    if button.clicked == 'delete':
        # do delete action
    elif button.clicked == 'update':
        # do update action

    return 'Complete'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask Python Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794695/flask-python-buttons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<input>` elements with the same `name`, but with different `value` attributes.

```
 <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="update">
 <input type ="submit" name="submit" value="delete">
```

On the backend, import the request object and deploy it conditionality:

```
from flask import request

if request.form.post['submit'] == 'update':
    ...
elif request.form.post['submit'] == 'delete':
    ...
else
    ...
```

Comment: This gave me an error, but `if request.form['submit']` worked. This statement was nested under `if form.validate_on_submit():`, not sure if that changes something in my case? I'm not well versed in routes.