# Flask getting same page result based on a button activated

Tags: python, html, flask, buttonclick

I'm learning Flask now.
Trying to achieve the calculation result to be displayed on the same page as the input fields, but also based on the button activated ("+" or "-") by the user before hitting the "result" button.

I'm getting the following error:

*TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.*

I tried following recommendations on [Flask Python buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19794695/flask-python-buttons/19794878), but those seem to only be working when redirecting to a new page.

**a piece of app.py:**

```
@app.route('/calculate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def calculate():
    form = InputForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        if "+" in request.form:
            result = Percentage.function1(form.x.data, form.y.data)
        elif "-" in request.form:
            result = Percentage.function2(form.x.data, form.y.data)
    else:
        result = None

        return render_template('calc.html',
                           form=form, result=result)
```

percentage.py:

```
class Percentage():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def function1(cls, x, y):
        result = round((x / (100 + y) * 100), 2)
        return result

    @classmethod
    def function2(cls, x, y):
        result = round((x * (y / 100 + 1)), 2)
        return result
```

**model.py:**

```
from wtforms import Form, FloatField, validators

class InputForm(Form):
    x = FloatField(
        label='first number',
        validators=[validators.InputRequired()])
    y = FloatField(
        label='second number',
        validators=[validators.InputRequired()])
```

**calc.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>


<div class="container page-form">
  <body>
    <form id="calc-form" method=post action="">
      <table>
        {% for field in form %}
          <tr>
            <br>
            <td>{{ field }}</td>
            <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </table>
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" name="+" type="submit" value="+" aria-pressed="true">+</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm active" name="-" type="submit" value="-" aria-pressed="true">-</a></p>
      <br><br>
      <p>
        <input type=submit value=Calculate></p></form>
      <p>
      {% if result != None %}
        <td>{{ result }}</td>
      {% endif %}
      </p>
    </body>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hey welcome to SO , can you please update what's in `request.form` by just `print(request.form)` :) ?

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean to just check   _def calculate():  print(request.form)_   ? This yields the same TypeError. And if I add it to the existing code here:     _if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate(): print(request.form)... _            I don't get to see any changes...

Comment: I meant you are checking this `if "+" in request.form:` so does `+` exists in `request.form` ? if not view function is going to return None which is your current Error

Comment: Oh, right! Checked it, it seems it doesn't exists, so the problem must be in the HTML button bit?

Comment: you have to check as : `if(request.form.get['name'] == '+')` instead of `if "+" in request.form:`, may be this should work , let me know